# d3.js grid lines hangs over x axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add grid lines to the back of my line chart, however the grid lines don't end at the last entry on the x axis. See plnk below;

http://plnkr.co/edit/j8qQ19m4l4jgdCsRu1da?p=preview

for reference, I'm looking for something like this;

[image]

Although, I'm not sure how easy it would be to add a blank entry into the x axis to push the line chart into the middle.

Anyway, I hope someone might be able to help with this!

Thanks

---

JS

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 11, 31)])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(d3.time.months)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B"))
  .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
  .innerTickSize(-height)
  .tickPadding(15)

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .innerTickSize(-width)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(15)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(new Date(2016, moment(d.date, 'MMMM').format('M') - 1, 1));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

  svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

});

function type(d) {
  d.date = d.date;
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}
```

TSV

```
date    close
January 50
February    100
March   75
April   90
May 85
June    40
July    30
August  35
September   12
October 72
November    77
December    5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your dates.You have the following :

```
 .domain([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 11, 31)])
```

This generates the December tick and then the rest after as you have a value in your TSV of `December 5` . If you want to go back a month, so to speak, just edit this to the month before :

```
 .domain([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 10, 31)])
```

Updated Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/vKlCFpBvDi097337HJyW?p=preview

Comment: One small thing should have been
`.domain([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 11, 1)])`
Nov  has just 30 days :P

Comment: @Cyril Haha guess I missed that one :L